# How to make a docker-compose file from command lline

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run my container by five Docker commands as follows:

- `docker run --privileged -d -v /root/docker/data:/var/lib/mysql -p 8888:80 testimg:2 init`
- `docker ps` ---> to get container ID
- `docker exec -it container_id bash`
- `docker exec container_id systemctl start mariadb`
- `docker exec container_id systemctl start httpd`

I was trying to do these steps by docker-compose but failed.

Can somebody make a docker-compose.yml or Dockerfile to get same result for me?

Comment: I did 4 and 5 step at another terminal

Comment: What was the errors you got, adding more information about the errors will help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be be able to do this with just a `docker-compose.yml`, because a compose file doesn't have any mechanism similar to `docker exec`. Additionally, running `systemd` (or really any process manager) inside a container is an anti-pattern. It can complicate the management and scaling of your containers, and in most cases doesn't provide you with any benefits.

Why don't you just have two images:

- One that starts `mariadb`
- One that starts Apache `httpd`

That might look something like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - "8888:80"

  db:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - "/root/docker/data:/var/lib/mysql"
```

You would probably need a custom image for the web server containing whatever application you're running, but you can definitely use the official mariadb image for your database.